# IEEE style citations with org-cite?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I want to export from org-mode to PDF with IEEE style citations. The IEEE style is roughly this:

```
Introduction
Here is a citation [1].
Methods, Results, etc.

References
[1] J. Doe and J. Doe, "Paper Title," in SomeJournal, 2022, pp. 99-120
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [csl](https://citationstyles.org/publishers/) with [citeproc](https://github.com/andras-simonyi/citeproc-el).

You can download an IEEE style in csl format from [here](https://github.com/citation-style-language/styles/blob/master/ieee.csl) and save it locally.

```
#+BIBLIOGRAPHY: cite.bib

* Heading 1
Refer to [cite:@ding2019asm2vec] for more information.
Also I should mention [cite:@grover2016node2vec].
Sometimes we have multiple sources at once, like [cite:@grover2016node2vec;@ding2019asm2vec].

* References
#+CITE_EXPORT: csl ~/repo/papers/templates/ieee.csl
#+PRINT_BIBLIOGRAPHY:
```

with a bibliography file

```
@inproceedings{grover2016node2vec,
  title={node2vec: Scalable feature learning for networks},
  author={Grover, Aditya and Leskovec, Jure},
  booktitle={Proceedings of the 22nd ACM SIGKDD international conference on Knowledge discovery and data mining},
  pages={855--864},
  year={2016}
}

@inproceedings{ding2019asm2vec,
  title={Asm2vec: Boosting static representation robustness for binary clone search against code obfuscation and compiler optimization},
  author={Ding, Steven HH and Fung, Benjamin CM and Charland, Philippe},
  booktitle={2019 IEEE Symposium on Security and Privacy (SP)},
  pages={472--489},
  year={2019},
  organization={IEEE}
}
```

Result looks like this:

[image]

[edit] User Simka suggested in the comments to add hanging indent to the bibliography with this change:

```
- <bibliography entry-spacing="0" second-field-align="flush">
+ <bibliography entry-spacing="0" second-field-align="flush" hanging-indent="true">
```

Comment: +1 although he formatting of the references needs some improvement: presumably it needs a special enclosure (something like `\begin{thebibliography}...\end{thebibliography}` in LaTeX) and not a regular section - but I could not find an example. I'll keep looking.

Comment: Great suggestion! Ideally it should render with the `[numerals]` not indented and any wrapped lines of each reference indented. But `\begin{thebiliograpy}` doesn't quite do it.

Comment: Yo can change the indentation by opening the IEEE style file in a text or xml editor (e.g., Emacs), and add hanging indent to the bibliography formatting parameters by changing the line '<bibliography entry-spacing="0" second-field-align="flush>" to ''<bibliography entry-spacing="0" second-field-align="flush" hanging-indent="true">'

Comment: Thank you @Simka that works great!

Comment: FYI, the Org mode development branch (what will be v. 9.7 eventually) now has some changes that should radically improve the LaTeX rendering of CSL styles out of the box, in particular that of labelled/second field aligned styles such as IEEE.