# How to make org-cite export multiple citations enclosed in one pair of brackets?

Tags: org-export

When I have multiple org-cite citations like this:

```
As described by [cite:@ref1;@ref2;@ref3]
```

My configuration exports with multiple bracketed numbers like this:

```
As described by [1], [2], [3]
```

But instead I want it to look like this:

```
As described by [1, 2, 3]
```

I am using IEEE templates as described [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/72292/10036).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this type of formatting is dictated by the CSL style (ieee.csl). You need to use a different style or (more adventurously) can try to modify ieee.csl.

Comment: That is perhaps more helpful than you thought it might be! I didn't know where to start looking, and modifying ieee.csl sounds more fun than diving into org-cite's elisp code.

Comment: Depends on your definition of fun :-), but if you choose this route then the [visual CSL editor](https://editor.citationstyles.org/visualEditor/) might come in handy.

Comment: There's an intimidating level of customization available there, but still; nice link.